# Why is django returning my HTML code when using a variable with the value retained from a filter?

Tags: python, django

I'm a beginner at learning Django and I have a website with a part that allows you to list your uncompleted . So far, I only want to display it and whenever I use a filter with this second variable ({"items": todos} that I want to be displayed in the template it returns the HTML skeleton.

*Everything works fine when I don't add this variable in the return statement. I have even tried printing the result from the  filter and it works perfectly.

```
def dashboard(response):
print(response.user.username)
if response.method == 'POST':
    form = CreateNewList(response.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        n = form.cleaned_data['name']
        t = ToDoList(name=n)
        t.save()
        response.user.todolist.add(t)
else: 
     form = CreateNewList()
     todos = ToDoList.objects.filter(user=response.user)
     print(todos)
     return render(response, 'classy_main/dashboard.html',{"items": todos},{"form":form})
return render(response, 'classy_main/dashboard.html',{"form":form, "list": t})
```

This is how the html looks(it returns the whole page from the "" to the script tags at the bottom, but just to give you an idea):

```
   <div class="news links nav-content">News</div>
  <div class="more links nav-content">More</div>
    <div class="notification">
      <a href="#" class="notification">
        <span><i class="fa fa-bell" style="font-size: 30px"></i></span>
        <span class="badge"></span>
      </a>
      
    </div>
    <div class="logOut">
```

is what I get back instead of the real page.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it, i just set the same able for both case so u could return the same thing for either case while still performing different tasks

```
def dashboard(response):
print(response.user.username)
if response.method == 'POST':
    form = CreateNewList(response.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        n = form.cleaned_data['name']
        todos = ToDoList(name=n)
        todos.save()
        response.user.todolist.add(todos)
        items = ToDoList.objects.filter(user=response.user)
else: 
     form = CreateNewList()
     items = ToDoList.objects.filter(user=response.user)
     print(items)
return render(response, 'classy_main/dashboard.html',{"form":form, "items": items})
```

i still dont know why it was returning the html skeleton page instead, anyways now i have a new problem when i refresh the page if there's some value(text) in the input field it adds it again to my todolist